# Maximum length of zigzag sequence

Tags: algorithm

A sequence of integers is called zigzag sequence if each of its elements is either strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors.

**Example :** The sequence 4 2 3 1 5 3 forms a zigzag, but 7 3 5 5 2 and 3 8 6 4 5 don't.

For a given array of integers we need to find the length of its largest (contiguous) sub-array that forms a zigzag sequence.

Can this be done in O(N) ?

Currently my solution is O(N^2) which is just simply taking every two points and checking each possible sub-array if it satisfies the condition or not.

Comment: Sahre your current logic for the solution, that will help others to determine the better logic.

Comment: @SuvenduShekharGiri I had done that. Its simply brute solution.

Comment: 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1~~~ the definition should be corrected, no?

Comment: @Dropout I didnt get your doubt

Comment: @Mrinal sorry my bad, too early in the morning :D

Comment: I have shown a simple proof of why and how a O(N) solution works...do you need a working sample code as well?

Comment: The described straightforward, brute-force algorithm is O(n^3), not O(n^2). Assuming you're testing at least 3-items segments and you test internal items only (no need to test the first or the last one) in each segment, the total number of tests in the worst case is (n^3 + 3n^2 - 4n + 3)/6.

Answer (score 2):

I claim that the length of overlapping sequence of any 2 zigzag sub-sequences is a most 1

Proof by contradiction:

Assume `a_i .. a_j` is the longest zigzag sub-sequence, and there is another zigzag sub-sequence `b_m...b_n` overlapping it.

without losing of generality, let's say the overlapping part is

> a_i ... a_k...a_j
>
> --------b_m...b_k'...b_n

a_k = b_m, a_k+1 = b_m+1....a_j = b_k'   where k'-m = j-k > 0  (at least 2 elements are overlapping)

Then they can merge to form a longer zig-zag sequence, contradiction.

This means the only case they can be overlapping each other is like

3 5 3 2 3 2 3

`3 5 3` and `3 2 3 2 3` is overlapping at 1 element

This can still be solved in O(N) I believe, like just greedily increase the zig-zag length whenever possible. If fails, **move iterator 1 element back and treat it as a new zig-zag starting point**

Keep record the latest and longest zig-zag length you have found

Answer (score 0):

For each index `i`, you can find the smallest `j` such that the subarray with index j,j+1,...,i-1,i is a zigzag. This can be done in two phases:

Find the longest "increasing" zig zag (starts with `a[1]>a[0]`):

```
start = 0
increasing[0] = 0
sign = true
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++)
  if ((arr[i] > arr[i-1] && sign) || )arr[i] < arr[i-1] && !sign)) {
      increasing[i] = start
      sign = !sign
  } else if (arr[i-1] < arr[i]) { //increasing and started last element
     start = i-1
     sign = false
     increasing[i] = i-1
  } else { //started this element
      start = i
      sign = true
      increasing[i] = i
  }
}
```

Do similarly for "decreasing" zig-zag, and you can find for each index the "earliest" possible start for a zig-zag subarray.

From there, finding the maximal possible zig-zag is easy.

Since all oporations are done in `O(n)`, and you basically do one after the other, this is your complexity.

You can combine the both "increasing" and "decreasing" to one go:

```
start = 0
maxZigZagStart[0] = 0
sign = true
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++)
  if ((arr[i] > arr[i-1] && sign) || )arr[i] < arr[i-1] && !sign)) {
      maxZigZagStart[i] = start
      sign = !sign
  } else if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) { //decreasing:
     start = i-1
     sign = false
     maxZigZagStart[i] = i-1
  } else if (arr[i-1] < arr[i]) { //increasing:
      start = i-1
      sign = true
      maxZigZagStart[i] = i-1
  } else { //equality
     start = i
     //guess it is increasing, if it is not - will be taken care of next iteration
     sign = true 
     maxZigZagStart[i] = i
  }
}
```

You can see that you can actually even let go of `maxZigZagStart` aux array and stored local maximal length instead.

Comment: Forgot else if case and from phone now. Will edit in 10 minutes

Comment: Ok sure. And please post if both can be handled in one go

Comment: @Mrinal Fixed. sorry 'bout it/

Answer (score 0):

Walk along the array and see if the current item belongs to (fits a definition of) a zigzag. Remember the las zigzag start, which is either the array's start or the first zigzag element after the most recent non-zigzag element. This and the current item define *some* zigzag subarray. When it appears longer than the previously found, store the new longest zigzag length. Proceed till the end of array and you should complete the task in O(N).

Answer (score 0):

A sketch of simple one-pass algorithm. Cmp compares neighbour elements, returning -1, 0, 1 for less, equal and greater cases. 
Zigzag ends for cases of Cmp transitions:

```
0 0
-1 0
1 0
```

Zigzag ends and new series starts:

```
0 -1
0 1
-1 -1
1 1
```

Zigzag series continues for transitions

```
-1 1
1 -1
```

Algo:

```
Start = 0
LastCmp =  - Compare(A[i], A[i - 1]) //prepare to use the first element individually
MaxLen = 0
for i = 1 to N - 1 do
    Cmp = Compare(A[i], A[i - 1])  //returns -1, 0, 1 for less, equal and greater cases
    if Abs(Cmp  - LastCmp) <> 2 then 
        //zigzag condition is violated, series ends, new series starts
        MaxLen = Max(MaxLen, i - 1 - Start)
        Start = i
    //else series continues, nothing to do
    LastCmp = Cmp
//check for ending zigzag
if LastCmp <> 0 then
    MaxLen = Max(MaxLen, N - Start)
```

examples of output:

```
2 6 7 1 7 0 7 3 1 1 7 4 
5         (7 1 7 0 7)
8 0 0 3 5 8 
1
0 0 7 0 
2
1 2 0 7 9 
3
8 3 5 2 
4
1 3 7 1 6 6 
2
1 4 0 6 6 3 4 3 8 0 9 9 
5
```

Comment: Whats (Cmp <> - LastCmp) ?

Comment: `<>` denotes `is not equal`  (`!=` in C-like languages)

Comment: 2 Doubts first (Cmp <> - LastCmp) means Cmp is less thn or greater than LastCmp  ? Second  //else series continues, nothing to do
    LastCmp = Cmp should be in else ?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, replaced

Comment: More errors have been found and corrected,  now my code passes tests

Comment: U sure the first case, answer is 7,1,7,0,7 but not 6,7,1,7,0,7,3?

Comment: @shole It corresponds to condition " strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors". Author examples don't allow to clarify - should elements like 6 and 3 be included in zigzag?

Comment: I think it almost is common sense or self explain...but okay lets look at his definition " A sequence of integers is called zigzag sequence if each of its elements is either strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors" and obviously 6 and 3 in the sequence (6,7,1,7,0,7,3) has only one neighbor so they must fulfil this condition, while all other numbers fulfil this condition too, so i think it is a longer zig zag subsequence than your output

Comment: I considered your interpretation too, but chose another variant to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I use perl to write this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@a = ( 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 8, 6, 4, 5 );

$n = scalar @a;

$best_start = 0;
$best_end = 1;
$best_length = 2;
$start = 0;
$end = 1;
$direction = ($a[0] > $a[1]) ? 1 : ($a[0] < $a[1]) ? -1 : 0;
for($i=2; $i<$n; $i++) {
    // a trick here, same value make $new_direction = $direction
    $new_direction = ($a[$i-1] > $a[$i]) ? 1 : ($a[$i-1] < $a[$i]) ? -1 : $direction;

    print "$a[$i-1] > $a[$i] : direction $new_direction Vs $direction\n";

    if ($direction != $new_direction) {
        $end = $i;
    } else {
        $this_length = $end - $start + 1;
        if ($this_length > $best_length) {
            $best_start = $start;
            $best_end = $end;
            $best_length = $this_length;
        }
        $start = $i-1;
        $end = $i;
    }
    $direction = $new_direction;
}

$this_length = $end - $start + 1;
if ($this_length > $best_length) {
    $best_start = $start;
    $best_end = $end;
    $best_length = $this_length;
}

print "BEST $best_start to $best_end length $best_length\n";
for ($i=$best_start; $i <= $best_end; $i++) {
    print $a[$i], " ";
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider sequence `5 9 3 4 5 4 2 3 6 5 2 1 3` as an example. You have a condition which every internal element of subsequence should satisfy (element is strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors). Lets compute this condition for every element of the whole sequence:

```
5 9 3 6 5 7 2 3 6 5 2 1 3
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

The condition is undefined for outermost elements because they have only one neighbor each. But I defined it as `0` for convenience.

The longest subsequence of `1`'s (`9 3 6 5 7 2`) is the internal part of the longest zigzag subsequence (`5 9 3 6 5 7 2 3`). So the algorithm is:

1. Find the longest subsequence of elements satisfying condition.
2. Add to it one element to each side.

The first step can be done in `O(n)` by the following algorithm:

```
max_length = 0
current_length = 0
for i from 2 to len(a) - 1:
    if a[i - 1] < a[i] > a[i + 1] or a[i - 1] > a[i] < a[i + 1]:
        current_length += 1
    else:
        max_length = max(max_length, current_length)
        current_length = 0
max_length = max(max_length, current_length)
```

The only special case is if the sequence total length is `0` or `1`. Then the whole sequence would be the longest zigzag subsequence.

Comment: With a sequence like: `9, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 8, 4` this will only find `3, 5` and `2, 8` yielding a max of 2 even though there are valid sub-arrays: `5, 3, 5, 3` with a length of 4 as well as `3, 2, 8, 4`

Comment: @CTS_AE, this is not true. See the second step about adding one element on each side to the longest subsequence of ones

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream" 
using namespace std ;

int main(){

    int t ; scanf("%d",&t) ;

    while(t--){

    int n ; scanf("%d",&n) ;

    int size1 = 1 , size2 = 1 , seq1  , seq2 , x ;
    bool flag1 = true  , flag2 = true ;

    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        scanf("%d",&x) ;

        if( i== 1 )seq1 = seq2 = x ;

        else {

            if( flag1 ){

                if( x>seq1){
                    size1++ ;
                    seq1 = x ;
                    flag1 = !flag1 ;
                }

                else if( x < seq1 )
                    seq1 = x ;
            }

            else{

                if( x<seq1){
                    size1++ ;
                    seq1=x ;
                    flag1 = !flag1 ;
                }

                else if( x > seq1 )
                    seq1 = x ;

            }

            if( flag2  ){

                if( x < seq2 ){
                    size2++ ;
                    seq2=x ;
                    flag2 = !flag2 ;
                }

                else if( x > seq2 )
                    seq2 = x ;

            }

            else {

                if( x > seq2 ){
                    size2++ ;
                    seq2 = x ;
                    flag2 = !flag2 ;
                }

                else if( x < seq2 )
                    seq2 = x ;
            }

        }
    }

    printf("%d\n",max(size1,size2)) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```